# Reorder the levels of multiple categorical variables using a vector of variable names

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a large dataset with factor variables but would like to only reorder the levels of a list of variables, titled "myvars" below. I want to reorder the levels for the purposes of summarizing them in a way that makes sense in a table 1. However when I try to change the order of the levels of the entire vector of variables in my dataset, I keep getting an error: Error: Assigned data `value` must be compatible with existing data...

Sample data:

```
donuts <- c("moderately","a lot","a lot","a lot","a little bit")
cookies <- c("a lot","a lot","not at all","moderately","a lot")
cupcakes <- c("not at all","not at all","a lot","moderately","a little bit")
coffee <- c("a little bit","not at all","moderately","a little bit","not at all")
macarons <- c("a little bit","moderately","not at all","not at all","a little bit")
dataset <- as.data.frame(donuts,cookies,cupcakes,coffee,macarons)
```

```
myvars <- c("donuts","cookies","cupcakes")

dataset[,myvars] <- factor(dataset[,myvars],levels=c("Not at all","Moderately","A little bit","A lot"))
```

Or should I use a loop? Any advice is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You are missing the `unlist` function ie: `dataset[,myvars] <- factor(unlist(dataset[,myvars]),levels=c("Not at all","Moderately","A little bit","A lot"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lapply` to to change factor levels in multiple columns. Also make sure that factor levels are same as in your data, otherwise it would return `NA`. In your attempt you are using mixed upper and lower case whereas in your data it is only lower case.

```
dataset[, myvars] <- lapply(dataset[, myvars], factor, 
                      levels=c("not at all","moderately","a little bit","a lot"))
```

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>%
  mutate(across(myvars, factor, 
               levels=c("not at all","moderately","a little bit","a lot")))
  #In older version of dplyr use mutate_at
  #mutate_at(vars(myvars), factor, 
               levels=c("not at all","moderately","a little bit","a lot"))
```

**data**

```
dataset <- data.frame(donuts,cookies,cupcakes,coffee,macarons)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `unlist` function  ie:

```
dataset[,myvars] <- factor(unlist(dataset[,myvars]),
                levels=c("Not at all","Moderately","A little bit","A lot"))
```